# Does a non metro UI windows store app get rejected after app submission to windows store?

Tags: cordova, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs, visual-studio-cordova

Hi we have developed an iOS cordova app using sencha frame work for UI and we want to port it to windows 8.

The UI design is not the metro UI design which is followed for windows store apps , if we continue with the same design will the app get rejected in the windows store after submission ?

Comment: If this is a requirement from windows for apps for the store, yes it'll be rejected. If not, it will not be rejected.

Comment: Does the windows store requires all apps to follow the Metro UI design strictly ? As most of our UI is working we would like to use the same and we and not uploaded any app to windows store earlier.

Comment: In a trice i couldn't find anything that speaks against a design which you created on your own. I think you just try it, maybe it works, maybe not. If they reject the application you can still bother about another UI. :-)

Comment: @Sithys Wins for worst comment ever.

Answer (score 4):

Your UI design choices are up to you.  The certification requirements are here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx   You will see many apps in the store that to not follow the Modern Guidance and your app needs to only follow the requirements published.